# MySql Community Server port changing

Tags: mysql, oracle-linux

I've installed mysql-community-server 8.0 on Oracle Linux 7 using [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.7-en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html)

It have been installed successfully, but:

```
# service mysqld start
```

resulted in:

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start mysqld.service
Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.


[root@myhost tmp]# journalctl -xe
Oct 02 16:19:29 myhost systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysqld.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysqld.service has begun starting up.
Oct 02 16:19:39 myhost systemd[1]: mysqld.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 02 16:19:39 myhost systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysqld.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysqld.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Oct 02 16:19:39 myhost systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
Oct 02 16:19:39 myhost systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.

[root@myhost tmp]# vi /var/log/mysqld.log
2019-10-02T13:19:36.151426Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.17) starting as process 21346
2019-10-02T13:19:38.162471Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-10-02T13:19:38.165671Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010262] [Server] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
2019-10-02T13:19:38.165697Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010257] [Server] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2019-10-02T13:19:38.166475Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-10-02T13:19:38.958654Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.17)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

[root@myhost tmp]# ps aux | grep mysql
root      2031  0.0  0.0 115388  3108 ?        S    11:59   0:00 /bin/sh /opt/zbox/run/mysql/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/opt/zbox/etc/mysql/my.cnf
nobody    2487  0.0  0.4 525380 36448 ?        Sl   11:59   0:00 /opt/zbox/run/mysql/mysqld --defaults-file=/opt/zbox/etc/mysql/my.cnf --basedir=/opt/zbox/run/mysql --datadir=/opt/zbox/data/mysql --plugin-dir=/opt/zbox/run/lib/mysql/plugin --user=nobody --log-error=/opt/zbox/logs/mysql_error.log --pid-file=/opt/zbox/tmp/mysql/mysqld.pid --socket=/opt/zbox/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306
```

I've found that mysql-community-server's configuration file located by path: `/etc/my.cnf`. But it contains no information about port setting. `/etc/my.cnf.d/` folder is empty.

How could I change its port?

Comment: From the same official documentation you link to https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.7-en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_port

Comment: However, you are likely to run into other issues running two versions of Mysql on the same machine -- pid files, database directories, sockets, ....

Comment: yes, I've used port = 3307 in config file and mysqld started, but I could not log in into it: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`. You're right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-systemd.html#systemd-multiple-mysql-instances suggests that the port may not specified in `my.cnf` but in the `mysqld.service` systemd unit.

Locate the `mysqld.service` file (try `/lib/systemd/system/` or `/etc/systemd/system/`) and change the port inside that file as explained in the documentation.